# Rotate existing polygon SpatiaLite in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I'm not good at all with SQL, so maybe the question is trivial.

I have a polygon loaded in a SpatiaLite DB and I'm using DB Manager in QGIS.

What I'm trying to do is to rotate the polygon by a given number (in degrees) using the `RotateCoords` function.  The syntax should be:

```
CREATE TABLE rotated as 
SELECT RotateCoords(Geometry, 45) AS Geometry from my_table
```

It seems to work, but I have to major issues:

1. How can I select all the fields from `my_table` in the same query? I'd like to maintain the same table, just rotate it. Another option could be to update the Geometry column of the existing table
2. The query of above creates a simple table, when I try to update the Geometry column and make the table as a spatial table it seems that nothing happens:

> ```
> SELECT RecoverGeometryColumn(‘rotated’, ‘Geometry’, 3003 , ‘MULTIPOLYGON’, ‘XY’)
> ```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You must pick also all the attributes into the new table with SELECT. Another option is to select only primary key and geometry and join the attributes from the original table. About registering the new table, I am not sure if RotateCoords can change one part multipolygons into single part but I would try if 'GEOMETRY' works instead of 'MULTIPOLYGON'. Spatialite-gui may be a better tool for this.

Comment: can i do it in the same query? or should I select the geometry and PK columns, perform the rotation with this table and then join all the attributes?

Comment: I recommend just to sit down and write `select RotateCoords(Geometry, 45) AS Geometry, attr_1, attr_2, attr_3, attr_4 ... from...`